# How to change the database connection in YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have yii application,, and i want to change the database connection..
first, my app is connect to 'trackstar' database, and later i want to change to 'taskmanagement' database..

So i just simply change the dbname in my code :

```
    <?php

// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Console Application',
    // application components
    'components'=>array(
         'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=taskmanagement',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'authManager'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID'=>'db',
            'itemTable' => 'tbl_auth_item',
            'itemChildTable' => 'tbl_auth_item_child',
            'assignmentTable' => 'tbl_auth_assignment',
        ),
    ),
);
```

but when i run the app i got error :

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: **Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table 'trackstar.tbl_auth_assignment**'
>   doesn't exist. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM
>   `tbl_auth_assignment`
>       WHERE userid=:userid

the thing i dont understand is that why is still connect to `trackstar` database eventhough i just change the dbname to `taskmanagement`

thx before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only configure the **console.php** Configuration . But Yii Web application use the **main.php**

Check your **main.php** file

its located on **Your App folder -> Protected -> config ->main.php**

Change Db connection on this file

Answer (score 2):

I guess one your model queries written as straight SQL query.

EX:

```
 SELECT * FROM databaseName.tableName
```

So, Even you change the database name in the config file these kinds of queries may not work. Please check your code in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to update database dynamically

```
        if ($city == 'ABC') {
            $databse = 'db_abc';
        } elseif ($city == 'BCD') {
            $databse = 'db_bcd';
        }   else {
            $databse = 'default_db';
        }
        $db = Yii::$app->getDb();
        $db->dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$databse";
```

Hope this help to override database connection string